# I get confused to understand the choke on or off position of Yamaha Saluto RX

Tags: yamaha, choke

I am unable to understand which is the choke off position (up lever or down lever)

Answer (score 2):

The BikesIndia page has a good picture of the choke switch on a Saluto:

[image]

This shows clearly where on and off are. If yours is different, just try it. When cold, it may not start at all without the choke. Once the engine is warm, turning it off again will allow the engine to run more smoothly with less smoke.